# CSS is not working correctly in PHP display

Tags: php, html

I am trying to connect php with css file through html

```
<?php

function print_error($message)
{
    echo "<html>\n";
    echo "<head>\n";
    echo "<title>Genes Catalogue </title>\n";
    echo "<link href=\"styles.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">\n";
    echo "</head>\n";
    echo "<body>\n";
    echo "<h1>Catalogue: Error found in the query</h1>\n";
    echo "<table>\n";
    echo "<tr><th>$message</th>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
    echo "<p><br><br></p>\n";
    echo "</p>\n";
    echo "</body>\n";
    echo "</html>\n";

    exit();
}
```

But the output code is plain.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thx

Comment: Your resulting HTML isn’t valid. Please [validate it](https://html5.validator.nu/) (you can copy the generated source from the browser view). If it still doesn’t work, use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource `style.css` _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: Notes: `\n` is not necessary or desirable in a HTML document. You forgot a `</tr>`. And you can make this whole code _far_ more readable and less error-prone by not using `echo` for every bit of HTML - instead, close the PHP tags, output the HTML as normal and then just open the PHP tags when you need something from PHP e.g. `<tr><th><?php echo $message; ?></th></tr>` would be one of the lines. Much easier to read (and therefore much easier to spot mistakes, and to maintain later).

Comment: Does the function get called anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
 when you are using html tags they have a clear meaning and browser understand it and they dont need to be the the diffrent lines so you can change your code like this:

```php
<?php

function print_error($message)
{
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<title>Genes Catalogue </title>";
    echo "<link href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet'>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<h1>Catalogue: Error found in the query</h1>";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>$message</th></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<p><br><br></p>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";

    exit();
}
```

I close the `tr` tag which you forgot it 
I remove the \n which was unnecessary 
I remove the `</p>` which doesnot have any open tag

Comment: When posting an answer, you should include all you've changed  why and how it solve the OP's problem. As far as I an see, there's no change here  that would make the CSS work, in comparison with the OP's version.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I update my answer

Comment: it is still invalid though!

Comment: now i think that is right :))